# Common Database Between iOS Devices

Tags: ios, database, macos

I am an novice programmer and I need a little direction.

Here is the concept of what I am looking to do:
Let's say I have an iOS and or OS X app for let's say storing people's names and phone numbers. Now I want to be able to have multiple people to be able to use the same app on different devices and access the same database; read and write values at the same time.

I am moderately well versed with Core Data and I have found that it works well but is not capable of accomplishing what I am trying to do.
Could someone point me in the right direction to find resources where I could learn how to do this? Thanks.

I apologize if the question has been asked before; I tried to do searches but I didn't know exactly what to search/could not find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you want to achieve will require an external database storage, which would provide an API that both your iOS and Mac OS apps will use in order to read/write to this *common database*.

There are plenty of resources on how to setup a database and an API. A pretty simple (yet heavy) approach would be to create a little web server in the language of your choice (PHP, Ruby on Rails, Node...) that exposes a hosted database, and communicate with that API from your apps. My advice if you are a beginner, would be to have a look at RoR to setup a simple web server/Restful API that exposes a MySQL database: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

If this is not the answer you're looking for, maybe you want to use iCloud in order to keep your data in sync between devices. However, this is not applicable in a multi-user land (e.g. this will work fine for multiple devices of the same user).

Comment: iCloud can be used with multiple users. Use CloudKit and the public database to share data between users.

Comment: Oh well I didn't know you could do this using iCloud only! Thanks for the heads up! Don't hesitate to edit my answer!

Comment: I think that what rmaddy mentioned with iCloud would work well for what I am currently looking to do. Plus I already know Core Data. Though I believe that if and when I look to expand the app and make it more of a social type app, a server database like one that Jordan Becker mentioned would be best. Thank you both for your help!